# Replacing class definition macros with templates

Tags: c++, templates

```
class ListItem
{
    ListItem*   GetPrev     ();
    ListItem*   GetNext     ();
    // ... and many more
};

class One : public ListItem
{
    One*    GetPrev () { return static_cast<One*>(ListItem::GetPrev()); }
    One*    GetNext () { return static_cast<One*>(ListItem::GetNext()); }
    // ... and many more overrides
};

class Two : public ListItem
{
    Two*    GetPrev () { return static_cast<Two*>(ListItem::GetPrev()); }
    Two*    GetNext () { return static_cast<Two*>(ListItem::GetNext()); }
    // ... and many more overrides
};

class Object : public One, public Two
{
};
```

The purpose of this is for the class Object to be inserted in two or more different lists. My question is how can I template One and Two? Since the name of the class also appears as the type, is this even possible? I have this covered by macros, but can it be done with templates? I don't mind if the code structure changes a bit, but can this be done without macros?

Comment: Have two [`std::list<Object>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can make `ListItem` a template:

```
template<class T>
class ListItem
{
    T*   GetPrev     ();
    T*   GetNext     ();
    // ... and many more
};

class One : public ListItem<One>
```

This is the curiously recurring template pattern.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. This actually crossed my mind but I didn't know if it's allowed and that even has a name, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use curiously recurring template pattern and even still have `ListItem` parent. But please consider using some `std::vector` or `std::list`, no need to reinvent template lists... Especially, that calls from `Object` level would have to look like that:

```
Object o;
One* prev = o.One::GetPrev();
```

Working code (http://ideone.com/dbmwFZ):

```
struct ListItem
{
    ListItem*   GetPrev     ();
    ListItem*   GetNext     ();
    // ... and many more
};

template <typename T>
struct ListItemT : ListItem
{
    T*    GetPrev () { return static_cast<T*>(ListItem::GetPrev()); }
    T*    GetNext () { return static_cast<T*>(ListItem::GetNext()); }
};

struct One : ListItemT<One>
{
};

class Two : public ListItemT<Two>
{
};

class Object : public One, public Two
{
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks for detailed code, voted the other answer for its simplicity though, hope you don't mind, both answers are awesome :)

Comment: @user3721806 no problem, as long as it helps :)